# Antennas and polarized radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization, antennas

What type of polarization  can we get from a dipole antenna? Circular? Linear? Elliptical? If there is a specific answer , what are the physical reasons?

Answer (score 2):

The emitted *radiation* field of an oscillating electric dipole is linearly polarised.

The physical reason is that the electrons are being accelerated along a specific direction defined by the direction of the antenna. At large distances from the antenna, the only non-zero electric-field component is that of a transverse electromagnetic wave, with an electric field perpendicular to the radial vector and in the plane defined by the direction of electron acceleration and the radial direction.
There is no electric field at right angles to this plane because there is no component of the electron acceleration in that direction. Since the transverse wave has an electric field confined to one plane then it is linearly polarised.

Comment: Rob, and the photon's spins in a half wave are all the same?